# How to add class for form label defined in cakephp and then add jquery event

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have created a form in cakephp

```
<?php echo $form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));?>
        <?php
          echo '<div class="loginbox">';
          echo '<table width="200" border="0">';
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>';
          echo $form->input('username', array('label' => __('Username', true)));
          echo '</td>';
          echo '<td>';
          echo $form->input('password', array('label' => __('Password', true))); 
          echo '</td>';             
          echo '<td>';
          echo $form->end('Login');
          echo '</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
          echo '</table>';
          echo '</div>';
        ?>
```

I want to add a class for label and after that add focus event of jquery so that in the input for username the text username appears and when clicked in the input area the text disappears. How to make it work?

Comment: consider using the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute instead, and perhaps looking for a JQuery fix for unsupported browsers.

Comment: Thanks Ross it solved all my problem

Comment: HTML5 placeholder does not work in IE7. Is there any fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

I would just bind the focus and blur events to your inputs. For each input, create a title attribute as your default text when the input is empty:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".forminput").focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });
    $(".forminput").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
        }
    });
    $(".forminput").blur();
});
</script>

<input value="" title="Enter a username" name="screenname" type="text" class="forminput" />
```